# 3d plot from debugger

Tags: plot, 3d, gdb

I would like to visualize my data in the debugger as good as possible. That means, when I have some 3D data in the form of for example `std::vector<glm::vec3>` I would like to create a scatterplot from it in the debugger. I am on linux and therefore my debugger is gdb. Are there gdb plugins that do something like this already? If not, how should I approach to do something like this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in.  It can be done, though.

One reasonably easy way to do it is to script gdb in Python.  Write some Python code to extract the data you want from the program you are debugging.  Then, send it to another process to display it.

Another way to do this is to try to make it display directly inside using gdb, again using the Python interface.  However, this is trickier because the GUI has to be run in a separate thread; and running separate threads in the gdb process has some issues.  See the [gdb-gui](https://github.com/tromey/gdb-gui) project for an example of how to accomplish this.